# Evaluating a variable number of expressions in R

Tags: r, differential-equations

Im trying to parse expressions from XML and then use them in deSolve's ode function.

The XML bit that defines the rates looks like this:

```
<model name="Lorenz">
    <state_variables>
        <variable id="X" name="x" value="1"/>
        <variable id="Y" name="y" value="1"/>
        <variable id="Z" name="z" value="1"/>
    </state_variables>
    <parameters>
        <variable id="a" name="a" value="-2.66"/>
        <variable id="b" name="b" value="-10"/>
        <variable id="c" name="c" value="28"/>
    </parameters>
    <rates>
        <variable id="dX" name="xchange" value="a*X+Y*Z"/>
        <variable id="dY" name="ychange" value="b*(Y-Z)"/>
        <variable id="dZ" name="zchange" value="-X*Y+c*Y-Z"/>
    </rates>
</model>
```

And my R object looks like this after parsing the variable leafs:

```
rates
expression(dX = a * X + Y * Z, dY = b * (Y - Z), dZ = -X * Y +  c * Y - Z)
```

My goal is to get these expressions in a function like this, but not hardcoded:

```
differentialRates= function(t, states, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(states, parameters)),{
    # This works but is still hardcoded:
    dX <- eval(rates[1])
    dY <- eval(rates[2])
    dZ <- eval(rates[3])
    # return the rate of change
    list(c(dX, dY, dZ))
  })
}
out <- ode(y = states, times = times, func = differentialRates, parms = parameters)
```

So if the `rates` vector changes because some other XML is loaded, the function `differentialRates` does not have to be changed.

Any insights would be very much appreciated.

*EDIT* As requested by Justin here is my code that parses the XML, I also expanded the XML above to be more inclusive.

```
extractVars = function(doc, model, node, key = "id", value = "value", numeric = FALSE, expression = FALSE){
  path = paste("/models/model[@name='",model, "']/", node, "/variable", sep="") #   Construct xpath
  xvars = xpathSApply(doc, path)  # Retrieve variable leafs
  xvars = sapply(xvars, xmlAttrs) # Retrieve attributes
  vars = as.vector(t(xvars[value,])) # Turn matrix (svars) into vector (vars)
  if(numeric){
    vars = as.numeric(vars)
  }
  if(expression){
    vars = mapply(parse, vars, text=vars)    
  }
  names(vars) = xvars[key,] # Apply names from matrix to vector
  return(vars)
}
```

Retrieve variables like this:

```
parameters = extractVars(doc, model="Lorenz", node="parameters", numeric=TRUE)
states = extractVars(doc, model="Lorenz", node="state_variables", numeric=TRUE)
rates = extractVars(doc, model="Lorenz", node="rates", expression=TRUE)
```

My guess is a function like this:

```
differentialRates <- function(t, y, parameters){
  return(lapply(rates, eval))
}
```

But this returns the error:

```
Error in split.default(rep_len(as.vector(e2), prod(dim(e1))), rep.int(seq_len(ncol(e1)),  : unimplemented type 'expression' in 'split'
```

Comment: you could do something like `return (lapply(rates, eval))`... but this sounds like you're opening yourself up to a lot of bad news down the line.  I'd be curious to know how you're getting the XML parsed and what the end goal here is... there must be a better way than blindly `eval`-ing parsed XML expressions!

Comment: @Justin I edited my question to include the information you requested, also I tried your suggestion but I get the same error I always get in my attempts: `The number of derivatives returned by func() (1) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (3)`. Somehow it seems to think the list of 3 is one expression or something. The point about this code is to load in differential models from XML, much more exiting stuff is planned for later on.

Comment: @Justin Got a different result with the function: `derivs4 <-function(t, y, parameters){
  return(lapply(rates, eval))
}`. The error is now: `Error in split.default(rep_len(as.vector(e2), prod(dim(e1))), rep.int(seq_len(ncol(e1)),  : 
  unimplemented type 'expression' in 'split'`